# selenium : how to handle error messages that get displayed when we dont give credentails

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium, and when testing a web application I want to check when credentials are wrong the message in alert which gets displayed and the error message that is displayed on the page after accepting the alert are same or not please can anybody help me how can I do this

I have handled alert using

```
web.swichto.alert().accept
```

but I want to compare the message that alert displays and the error message that is displayed in that page like

Error: Invalid User ID/Password Or Network Is Down!

and message in alert box like

Invalid username/password

thanks in advance

Comment: Use the method driver.switchTo().alert().getText(); This returns the text on the alert box and you can use assertion to assert the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store text present in the alert into a variable as follows,

```
String msg_in_alert=driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

then you can use assert to compare,

```
Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector_of_error_element")).getText().compareTo(msg_in_alert), true);
```

"true" specifies that the text should match..
If text does not match,it will result in step failure...

Comment: Hi for "selector of error element" the web page is giving as <spam> error message </spam> so what will be selector for that text displayed on we page..........                                                                                     thanks in advance

Comment: i think something is wrong with the selector that you have used,can you please paste it here?

Comment: Assert.assertEquals(web.findElement(By.cssSelector("error")).getText().compareTo(alertText),true);

Comment: "error" is not a selector,can u please paste ur html code,i'l help u choose the right one..

Comment: you can click [HERE](http://seleniumtestautomationtipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2013/01/finding-elements-using-class-selector.html) to learn about how to use a selector..

Comment: <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
<form action="/corept/j_spring_security_check" name="loginform" method="post">
<table style="border: 0px; width: 500px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">
<div style="color: red;">
<span style="font-weight: bold;">Error: </span>
<span>Invalid User ID/Password Or Network Is Down!</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>

Comment: Exception in thread "main" junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<-4> but was:<true>
 at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
 at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:283)
 at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:64)
 at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:71)

Answer (score -2):

```
WebElement element = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding error-class ng-hide']"));
        element.getText();

        if(element.equals("Recall and Volume data does not exist for calculation. Please upload the data.")){
            System.out.println("true");

        }else{
                System.out.println("false");
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    WebElement mandmessActionName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/form/div[1]/div/fieldset/div[1]/div/span[1]"));
    String mandmessActionName1 = mandmessActionName.getText();


    if (mandmessActionName1.equals("Action Name is required."))
        {
        System.out.println("true");

        }
    else
        {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
```